# More .htaccess redirect help needed

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have a bunch of links that have to be redirected... But there are only two kind of those links:

1. URLs like `http://mydomain.com/category/new%20york` should be redirected to `http://mydomain.com/category/New-York`, so, every space (or `%20`) should be "minus", and first letter should be upper case (in category name).
2. `http://mydomain.com/category/california` should be `http://mydomain.com/category/California`, so first letter have to be upper case.
3. Sure, if it is `http://mydomain.com/category/New%20York`, it should be `http://mydomain.com/category/New-York`.

Can you help me with those please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure that mod_rewrite itself can convert words into their uppercased versions nor switch `%20` into a `-` - you could however redirect to the lower-case version of the page, and let PHP set the record straight.

As far as I know, RewriteMap is only capable of converting a whole url to either upper- or lowercase... so you'll probably have to go with my suggestion above.

The code for that would be the following:

```
^category/([a-z\-\ ]+)(/)?$ index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

...and in php, you would want to do the following:

```
<?php
     //Get the category
     $cat = ( isset($_GET['category']) )? $_GET['category'] : '';

     //Check if we need to convert the url
     if( ($cat != '') && (strpos($cat, ' ') !== false) || !ctype_upper($cat[0]) ) {

        //$new_category = Word-Number-One
        $new_category = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords($cat));

        //Redirect to the new URL
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/category/' . $new_category);

     }         
?>
```

I've tried it out on my own server and it works just fine, so hopefully I didn't manage to cripple the code upon copying it to the textarea.

Comment: mod_rewrite can convert ALL characters to upper or lower case with help of `RewriteMap` (well, all of this can be achieved with RewriteMap using **prg:** type which will use some external script for rewriting) .. but for such complex requirement it is easier to do all of this via custom PHP script (or generate proper URLs in first place) as RewriteMaps are usually not available on shared hosting (as `RewriteMap` directive cannot be declared in htaccess context, only server config or virtual host).